# completionHandler - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I've following code, I'm getting error for completionHandler

**Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

I understand that it's due to mismatch for completionHandler. How do I return a string/meaningful details in error for completionHandler?

```
func fetch(urlString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
    
    //...

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Failed to create URL!")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(nil, "Bad URL") // gives error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing wrong parameter type for `Error?` to `completionHandler`. `Error?` is not a `String`.

---

To fix the issue create an `NSError` and use it instead of `String`:

```
let error = NSError(domain: "com.myAppPackageName", code: 1, userInfo: [
    NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Bad URL"
])
completionHandler(nil, error)
```

---

Or create a custom error enum type:

```
enum Error: String, Swift.Error {
    case badURL = "Bad URL"

    private var errorCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case .badURL:
            return 100 // your error code
        }
    }

    var foundationError: NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "com.myAppPackageName", code: errorCode, userInfo: [
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : self.rawValue
        ])
    }
}

...

completionHandler(nil, Error.badURL.foundationError)

...
```

Comment: Thanks, I know now what was wrong. The enum is also clear however I need to return NSLocalizedDescriptionKey as meaning info via completionHandler. How do we add NSLocalizedDescriptionKey into enum if possible?

Comment: You cannot add `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` into enum. You can extract enum description using `rawValue`, in this case `badURL.rawValue` would return "Bad URL" `String` .

Comment: @Raymond Updated my answer with possible `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` inclusion in enum Error